# "Distribute weights evenly" in code

Tags: java, android, button

I have one little problem...Here is my code..Is there a way to "distribute weights evenly" for those buttons what I made.. I tried to `button[i].setWidth()`.. but when I turn around my phone it looks ugly.. so Is there away to distribute buttons width auto?

```
    ViewGroup row1 = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.TableRow02);
    ViewGroup row2 = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.TableRow04);
    ViewGroup row3 = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.TableRow06);
    ViewGroup row4 = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.TableRow08);
    ViewGroup row5 = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.TableRow10);

    Button button[] = new Button[36];
    for(int i=1;i<36;i++)
    {
        button[i] = new Button(this);

        if(i==32||i==33||i==34||i==35){button[i].setVisibility(-1);}

        button[i].setText("700€");
        button[i].setTextSize(10);
        button[i].setWidth(20);

     // Insert buttons in rows
        if(i<8){row1.addView(button[i]);}
        else if(i<15){row2.addView(button[i]);}
        else if(i<22){row3.addView(button[i]);}
        else if(i<29){row4.addView(button[i]);}
        else if(i<36){row5.addView(button[i]);}
    }
```

Comment: Does this code work for you? You're calling `setVisibility(-1)`, but none of the constants defined in `View` has this value. Better use `View.VISIBLE`, `View.INVISIBLE` or `View.GONE` instead.

Comment: yeah.. this works for me.. but I will make changes..

Comment: You should try to replace most of your work with views into XML layouts. Creating a static layout is much more simple with XML, cause you can see what you're doing without building the whole application.

Comment: yeah.. but if i'll do this.. i need to define each button.. so 33 lines of similar text?..and I have 35 textViews more... so 35 lines of defining again?:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tactically, put the buttons in a `LinearLayout` and set `android:layout_weight="1"` for each of them.

Strategically, design a decent UI, one that does not involve a row of 36 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare said, instead of setting the width, you should consider to set the weight parameter of the buttons in order to achieve a flexible layout.

If you want to achieve this programmatically (i.e. in code and not in the XML layout), you can use the button's `setLayoutParams` method. I haven't tested it, but something like this should work:

```
// outside of loop
LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    1.0
);

....
// enter loop
....

button[i].setLayoutParams(p);
```

In this example, `1.0` represents the weight. The other two parameters represent `layout_width` and `layout_height` parameter.

But seriously, I can't imagine that a layout with 36 buttons is very user friendly :-)